# Repeated formula over a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a cell that I want to have a sum of all the cells below. So, I started with a simple `=SUM(E$3:E)` function.

Now, I want to add a modifier for each row. So my formula would now look something like this:

`=(E$3 * $D$3) + (E$4 * $D$4) + (E$5 * $D$5) ...`

Is there an easy way to make this smaller. I could do this formula, however I want to be able to add/remove rows easily without worrying about this cell.

Other Notes:

I will be autofilling this to the right so it needs to be able to work for all columns with the same modifier cell.

Comment: Use SUMPRODUCT(E$3:E,$D$3:$D)

Answer (score 0):

use this formula:

```
=INDEX(E3:E*D3:D)
```